# выборка из бд на соответствие регулярному выражению

Tags: mysql, sql, регулярные-выражения

Доброго времени! Хотелось бы узнать можно ли сделать выборку из базы данных на соответствие регулярному выражению, то есть есть база данных в которое в полях id1 и id2 записанные строки и в этих строках может встретиться произвольная цифра она экранирована в строке двумя скобками [] и к примеру выглядит так: 00-01:AD[22]SEL10 подскажите можно ли сделать выборку из бд к примеру на соответствие регулярному выражению, например выбрать только строки в которых цифра между фигурных скобок меньше определенного числа или больше или и то и то как ниже на примере?

```
$tmp = $db->query("SELECT * FROM diapar WHERE LOCATE(lower('[>9]'), lower(id1)) AND  LOCATE(lower('[<235]'), lower(id2))");
```

Дополню: база данных сайта phpMyAdmin использую диалект mysqli

Comment: А из какой именно БД. Многие современные СУБД имеют функции для работы с регулярными выражениями. Но в каждой СУБД они свои. их не сложно найти указав в гугле название БД и "регулярные выражения" или "regexp"

Comment: И кстати, странные у вас "регулярные выражения". то что называют регулярными выражениями не позволяет проверять на больше/меньше простыми методами. Как вы написали `[<235]` обозначает "один символ который 2 или 3 или 5 или <".

Comment: Добавил тег MySQL. но проблема с пониманием "регулярное выражение" все равно осталась. потому как регулярками такое не решается. я бы предложил обычными строковыми функциями http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/String_functions.html выделить кусок строки между скобками, преобразовать в число и проверять на больше/меньше

Comment: А если отвечать прямо на ваш вопрос "выборка из бд на соответствие регулярному выражению" то предложение regexp вам должно было бы помочь http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Regexp.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Напишите функцию, которая будет преобразовывать строку в число по указанным Вами правилам, а потом вызовите эту функцию в запросе

```
CREATE FUNCTION sf_str_to_int(in_str TEXT)
    RETURNS int(11)
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE var_pos_beg INTEGER;
  DECLARE var_pos_end INTEGER;
  DECLARE var_part TEXT;

  IF in_str IS NULL THEN
    RETURN NULL;
  END IF;

  SET var_pos_beg = LOCATE('[', in_str);
  IF var_pos_beg = 0 THEN
    RETURN NULL;
  END IF;

  SET var_pos_end = LOCATE(']', in_str, var_pos_beg);
  IF var_pos_end = 0 THEN
    RETURN NULL;
  END IF;

  SET var_part = SUBSTRING(in_str, var_pos_beg + 1, var_pos_end - var_pos_beg - 1);
  IF var_part REGEXP '^[[:digit:]]+$' THEN
    RETURN var_part;
  END IF;

  RETURN NULL;  
END;

SELECT * FROM diapar WHERE sf_str_to_int(id1) > 26;
```

Comment: а это получается функцию надо в самом ПХПМай Админе прописать или можно как php объявить? я просто не разу не использовал функции в sql до этого

Comment: @dantelol Это функция БД и должна находиться в базе

Answer (score 1):

Средствами MySQL влоб задачу решить нельзя. Используя регулярные выражения, можно только проверить на соответствие шаблону (функция REGEXP). То есть выбрать записи, где присутствует число в квадратных скобках - запросто, а выделить регулярками это число для последующего сравнения не получится.

Хотя формально задача решается - тем же методом, каким, например, режется произвольный диапазон IP-адресов на подсети. Жаль, это не шаблонизируется, хотя динамический SQL в рамках ХП реализовать можно (нафига только?).

Например, нужно выбрать записи, где число в квадратных скобках имеет значение от 9 до 125. Придётся проверить запись на соответствие шаблонам:

```
%[[]9[]]%
%[[][1-9][0-9][]]%
%[[]1[0-1][0-9][]]%
%[[]12[0-5][]]%
```

Если хотя бы одному шаблону соответствует (объединять через OR) - запись подходит.

Comment: Шаблоны НЕ учитывают возможность наличия ведущих нулей.

Comment: Зачем же 4 регулярки. одной вполне можно https://regex101.com/r/52W3IF/1

Comment: @Mike Да понятно, что любое количество альтернативных регулярок можно собрать в одну. Просто есть некий порог, выше которого начинается "многоэтажное безобразие" - у меня он невысок.